# ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so: undefined symbol: _PyCodec_LookupTextEncoding

Tags: python, django, pip

When I used command : `pip freeze` it shows message error follow:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
  from pip import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line in <module>
  from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
 import io
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 51, in <module>
 import _io
 ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so: undefined symbol: _PyCodec_LookupTextEncoding
```

which pip:

```
/usr/local/bin/pip
```

which python:

```
/usr/local/bin/python
```

I do not know why it's in error ! so I hope anybody can help me to resolve problem ! thank you.